# Обработка смайликов-символов

Tags: c#

Ввожу в приложении смайлики 
Но из-за них крашит. Как можно исправить?

```
if (!Regex.Match(strmessage, "^[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z0-9]+$").Success)
{
    return;
}
```

Вот если что ограничиваю ввод на Кириллицу и латиницу. Как можно разрешить ввод символов кроме смайликов или их как-то можно обработать ?

Comment: Лучше разберитесь, почему крашит, и сделайте чтоб не крашило, вместо того чтобы смайлики запрещать 

Comment: А крашит как именно? Исключение кидает или просто завершается без предупреждения?

Comment: Просто завершается. String формат поддерживает смайлы? @trollingchar

Comment: А как именно вводите смайлы в приложение?

Comment: @trollingchar Пример в вопросе

Comment: Я только что у себя проверил, ввод через `Console.ReadLine()` работает, если просто в коде строку со смайликами написать `""`, тоже работает.

Comment: @trollingchar А можно ли регулярным выражением проверить на наличие смайликов?